# Convert stringified list of dictionaries back to a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I know that to convert a dictionary to/from a string, I use `json.loads` and `json.dumps`. However, those methods fail when given a string representing a list of dictionaries. For example,

```
sample_entry = [
    {"type": "test", "topic": "obama", "interval": "daily"},
    {"type": "test", "topic": "biden", "interval": "immediate"},
]
```

Converting that to a string with `str()` gives us

```
"[{'topic': 'obama', 'interval': 'daily', 'type': 'test'}, {'topic': 'biden', 'interval': 'immediate', 'type': 'test'}]"
```

Is there an easy way of converting this back to a list of dictionaries? `eval` does precisely what I want, but I'm concerned about running it on a user-supplied string.

Is there another way of accomplishing this that will be robust in the face of varying list lengths and variable white space?

EDIT: While json.loads(json.dumps(sample_entry)) does indeed work, json.loads(str(sample_entry)) does not. The difference, it seems, is where single quotes and double quotes are used. The data source I'm receiving this string from is unlikely to be consistent in use of ' vs ", so I'd like to account for both.

Comment: _"those methods fail when given a string representing a list of dictionaries."_ They do? How so? I just tried `json.loads(json.dumps(sample_entry))` and I didn't get an exception or anything. Looks fine to me.

Comment: _"The data source I'm receiving this string from is unlikely to be consistent in use of ' vs ""_. Ok, that makes more sense. Thanks for the clarification. What do you know about the data source? Are they using Python? Are they using json? Can you convince them to use a more consistent syntax?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, and you're right about json.loads(json.dumps(sample_entry)) working fine. Unfortunately, the method that my data source is using sends me a string that doesn't match that given by json.dumps(). Further unfortunately, consistency on this isn't mine to request. It's a python app grabbing user-supplied, javascript-formatted data.

Comment: ```[
    {"type": "test", "topic": "obama", "interval": "daily"},
    {"type": "test", "topic": "biden", "interval": "immediate"},
]```if I try to validate```Invalid JSON: Expecting value: line 4 column 1 (char 128)
None

[Program finished] ```and when I try to parse```[{'type': 'test', 'topic': 'obama', 'interval': 'daily'}, {'type': 'test', 'topic': 'biden', 'interval': 'immediate'}]

[Program finished] ```meaning the example is right. Maybe post the data that didn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> my_str = "[{'topic': 'obama', 'interval': 'daily', 'type': 'test'}, {'topic': 'biden', 'interval': 'immediate', 'type': 'test'}]"

>>> ast.literal_eval(my_str)
[{'interval': 'daily', 'type': 'test', 'topic': 'obama'}, {'interval': 'immediate', 'type': 'test', 'topic': 'biden'}]
```

As per the [`ast.literal_eval` document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), it:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

Answer (score 5):

> Converting that to a string with str() gives us...

There's your problem right there. You shouldn't be using `str` to serialize data. There's no guarantee that the resulting string will be something that can be recovered back into the original object.

Instead of using `str()`, use `json.dumps`. I know you said you tried it and it didn't work, but it's quite robust when used on built-in objects, so I suspect you may have just accidentally made a typo. The example dict you give serializes perfectly:

```
>>> sample_entry = [
...     {"type": "test", "topic": "obama", "interval": "daily"},
...     {"type": "test", "topic": "biden", "interval": "immediate"},
... ]
>>>
>>> s = json.dumps(sample_entry)
>>> print(s)
[{"interval": "daily", "topic": "obama", "type": "test"}, {"interval": "immediate", "topic": "biden", "type": "test"}]
>>>
>>> d = json.loads(s)
>>> d
[{'interval': 'daily', 'topic': 'obama', 'type': 'test'}, {'interval': 'immediate', 'topic': 'biden', 'type': 'test'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

A well-formed python data type can in most case be interpreted using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval("[{'topic': 'obama', 'interval': 'daily', 'type': 'test'}, {'topic': 'biden', 'interval': 'immediate', 'type': 'test'}]")
Out[38]: 
[{'interval': 'daily', 'topic': 'obama', 'type': 'test'},
 {'interval': 'immediate', 'topic': 'biden', 'type': 'test'}]
```